# Does it make sense to calculate Q2 and R2 values on PLS-DA models?

Tags: cross-validation, r-squared, discriminant-analysis, partial-least-squares

Since PLS-DA is a computational technique which deals with outcomes expressed as a categorical variable (e.g. "Yellow","Brown","Black","Green") I cannot understand how it is possible to calculate Q2 and R2 values. In facts, these values are calculated based on the difference between the real outcome and the outcome predicted by the model after removal of some features; this procedure seems correct with continuous outcomes but how is it possible to perform a difference between "Green" and "Yellow" for instance? Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe the difference between "green" and "yellow" (or any other non-identical pair) can be taken as 1, as opposed to 0 in case of identical pairs? But in any case, it would be helpful to clarify what Q2 and R2 values are (I am familiar with $R^2$, but have never encountered "Q2") and to provide some larger context for your question.

Comment: there is a definition of Q2 on this page http://www.moleculardescriptors.eu/tutorials/T5_moleculardescriptors_models.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The R2 and Q2 are calculated using the labels in numerical form (-1 and 1 or 0 and 1 instead of green and yellow). 
However this measure are not perfectly suited for classification.

I believe that this paper will (partly) answer your question and provide an alternative to the Q2:
Discriminant Q2 (DQ2) for improved discrimination in PLSDA models
Westerhuis et al. Metabolomics Vol. 4, Number 4, 293-296
http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11306-008-0126-2